# Archive For Publishing on release version failing for Xamarin.Droid

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have created a Xamarin.Forms application and archived release version successfully for iOs version. While I am trying to archive release version for Android, the project is failing with below error.

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2,2): Error: Could not load assembly 'APPNAME, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
```

Please help on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

most of the time this happens if there were different dll versions in the same solution

- Right click on your solution and select Manage NuGet packages for solution
- go to installed tab
- check if there is a difference between versions of the nugets you used in iOs project.
- if it is, then uninstall that nuget and install same version to all projects

Comment: Both Android and iOS having same packages with same version. But still persisting the same archive issue. :/

Comment: is your project build without any errors? (both android and ios)

Comment: Yes builded without any errors and even working on real devices when running from system itself.

Comment: ok, first take a backup of your project. then open Package Manager Console and run this command:
Update-Package -reinstall  . after completed process,  rebuild project and try to archive again